# Append rle result from loop

Tags: r, loops, append, coin-flipping

I am running a coin-toss simulation with a loop which runs about 1 million times.

Each time I run the loop I wish to retain the table output from the RLE command. Unfortunately a simple append does not seem to be appropriate. Each time I run the loop I get a slightly different amount of data which seems to be one of the sticking points.

This code gives an idea of what I am doing:

```
N <- 5 #Number of times to run
rlex <-NULL
#begin loop#############################
for (i in 1:N) { #tells R to repeat N number
x <-sample(0:1, 100000, 1/2)
rlex <-append(rlex, rle(x))
}
table(rlex) #doesn't work
table(rle(x)) #only 1
```

So instead of having five separate rle results (in this simulation, 1 million in the full version), I want one merged rle table. Hope this is clear. Obviously my actual code is a bit more complex, hence any solution should be as close to what I have specified as possible.

UPDATE: The loop is an absolute requirement. No ifs or buts. Perhaps I can pull out the table(rle(x)) data and put it into a matrix. However again the stumbling block is the fact that some of the less frequent run lengths do not always turn up in each loop. Thus I guess I am looking to conditionally fill a matrix based on the run length number?

Last update before I give up: Retaining the rle$values will mean that too much data is being retained. My simulation is large-scale and I really only wish to retain the table output of the rle. Either I retain each table(rle(x)) for each loop and combine by hand (there will be thousands), or I find a programmatic way to keep the data (yes for zeroes and ones) and have one table that is formed from merging each of the individual loops as I go along.

Either this is easyish to do, as specified, or I will not be doing it. It may seem a silly idea/request, but that should be incidental to whether it can be done.

**Seriously last time**. Here is an animated gif showing what I expect to happen. [image]

After each iteration of the loop data is added to the table. This is as clear as I am going to be able to communicate it.

Comment: If you're using a for loop, I suggest you pre-allocate your `rlex` variable to accommodate the result. This will make things run way faster. Suggested reading on optimization: The R Inferno by Pat Burns.

Comment: I am not really bothered about speed. I have already run the simulation once, and the time it took was reasonable. I am interested in retaining the rle data and accommodating it within my already working code.

Comment: I might help to show what you expect to see returned. Anyway, why not have two vectors `lengths` and `values` and append each one rather than trying to append a complex list of two vectors. I would allocate storage rather than append but you can deal with that if you don't care about efficiency. I do wonder about having sufficient space to store these data in memory. It is wasteful to store all the information if all you need is the tabular summary.

Comment: In response to your second modification of the question: In my answer I show how to force `rle` to always have the same length if you sample from a factor.  Everything in R is easy, once you clearly specify what the problem is.

Comment: And for the record, I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: -1 (I did downvote) The question was very unclear about what was wanted at the time. It is getting better but I'm still having to deduce what is wanted from the trail of comments and updates. How about some expected output! If you show that we can dispense with the ambiguity and I can remove the downvote.

Comment: I voted to close it, but then all hell broke loose!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, attempt number 4:

```
N <- 5
set.seed(1)
x <- NULL
for (i in 1:N){
  x <- rbind(x, table(rle(sample(0:1, 100000, replace=TRUE))))
}

x <- as.data.frame(x)
x$length <- as.numeric(rownames(x))
aggregate(x[, 1:2], list(x[[3]]), sum)
```

Produces:

```
   Group.1     0     1
1        1 62634 62531
2        2 31410 31577
3        3 15748 15488
4        4  7604  7876
5        5  3912  3845
6        6  1968  1951
7        7   979   971
8        8   498   477
9        9   227   246
10      10   109   128
11      11    65    59
12      12    24    30
13      13    21    11
14      14     7    10
15      15     0     4
16      16     4     2
17      17     0     1
18      18     0     1
```

---

If you want the aggregation inside the loop, do:

```
N <- 5
set.seed(1)
x <- NULL
for (i in 1:N){
  x <- rbind(x, table(rle(sample(0:1, 100000, replace=TRUE))))
  y <- aggregate(x, list(as.numeric(rownames(x))), sum)
  print(y)
}
```

Comment: Although I am sure this works fine, I cannot use this in my (much more complex) code. I will either have to settle for thousands of individual tables (which I will have to combine by hand), or find a solution to my problem as stated in the question. Thanks though.

Comment: @RSoul I have answered your question as stated. You now are imposing additional constraints, although you haven't stated what they are.

Comment: @RSoul Since you modified your question to force a loop, I edited my answer.

Comment: I thought it was obvious that a loop was required. I clarified with the update. It was no bait-and-switch. Still your answer does not help me achieve my ends, clever as it is. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: The only thing that is obvious is that a loop is almost never required in R. If you find it frustrating that you don't get your desired response, perhaps it's because your question was vague and ambiguous? We try to help, but none of us have a crystal ball. Also, we find it much easier to help if the OP isn't snarky, and some of your comments have been bordering on the snarky end of the scale.

Comment: I wonder if you two are talking at crossed purposes? The OP doesn't want the number of 0s or 1s, but the run length data; i.e. `$lengths`. Even then they seem to only care about the summary not the actual data. And @RSoul, if 4+ SO users are having trouble understanding what it is that you want, I do wonder why you seem to think that it is our fault that we don't get what you want rather than the simpler hypothesis that you need to explain **and** show us what you want better. I did ask for expected output but you haven't edited that into your question, which would help clear up ambiguities.

Comment: @GavinSimpson yes, I can see that, but then the only reason for having the `rle` is to compute a table with it. (As far as I can tell.)

Comment: @Andrie That isn't my reading of this. Look at `table(rle(x))` from the OP's example. As far as I can tell, they want one of these summaries but over all 1 million simulations not for each separate `i`. They are interested in the distribution of the number of times they get runs of 0s and 1s, not the total number of 0s and 1s which your example gives. If the problem wasn't so big, I'd suggest storing output from `table()` in each loop, but summing the tabular elements each loop may be required given the 1 million simulation requirement.

Comment: I still don't think this is what the OP wants -- I think they want the cumulative sum of the tables ...

Comment: @RSoul OK, then use `aggregate` on the output. Answer edited.

Comment: @BenBolker Though the requested output supplied in the animated GIF doesn't appear to show this, just the final sum, does it not?

Comment: @Andrie I think this is still going to have lots of tables and then combines them, rather than having one table with a running cumulative as the loops progress. I will try it out though. Thank you again.

Comment: @RSoul then move the aggregation inside the loop.

Comment: @Andrie Am testing it now. We will see. Certainly nearer than I was some hours ago.

Comment: @RSoul Aggregation inside loop added

Answer (score 7):

Following up @CarlWitthoft's answer, you probably want:

```
N <- 5
rlex <-NULL
for (i in 1:N) {
    x <-sample(0:1, 100000, 1/2)
    rlex <-append(rlex, rle(x)$lengths)
}
```

since I think you don't care about the `$values` component (i.e. whether each run is a run of zeros or ones).

**Result**: one long vector of run lengths.

But this would probably be a lot more efficient:

```
maxlen <- 30
rlemat <- matrix(nrow=N,ncol=maxlen)
for (i in 1:N) { 
    x <-sample(0:1, 100000, 1/2)
    rlemat[i,] <- table(factor(rle(x)$lengths,levels=1:maxlen))
}
```

**Result**: an `N` by `maxlen` table of run lengths from each iteration.

If you only want to save the total number of runs of each length you could try:

```
rlecumsum <- rep(0,maxlen)
for (i in 1:N) { 
    x <-sample(0:1, 100000, 1/2)
    rlecumsum <- rlecumsum + table(factor(rle(x)$lengths,levels=1:maxlen))
}
```

**Result**: an vector of length `maxlen` of the total numbers of run lengths across all iterations.

And here's my final answer:

```
rlecumtab <- matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=maxlen)
for (i in 1:N) { 
   x <- sample(0:1, 100000, 1/2)
   r1 <- rle(x)
   rtab <- table(factor(r1$lengths,levels=1:maxlen),r1$values)
   rlecumtab <- rlecumtab + rtab
}
```

**Result**: a `maxlen` by 2 table of the total numbers of run lengths across all iterations, divided by type (0-run vs 1-run).

Comment: Actually this is near to as far as I have got. I think this is going to retain too much data. I really only need the output of the table(rle(x)), merged after each loop. If that is clear (seemingly not). Thanks though.

Comment: by "merged" do you mean you want to keep only the total number of runs of each length?  You can use `colSums(rlemat)` to collapse the matrix to totals, *or* you can set `rlecumsum <- rep(0,maxlen)` and then `rlecumsum <- rlecumsum + table(...)` in each loop iteration ...

Comment: Merged meant for each loop. The number of runs at length 1, 2, 3, 4 merged as a total, overall. Is it really that unclear?

Comment: well, yes, it was: "merged" is pretty vague, as the term also means combining columns of multiple tables into a single table ... showing the **desired output** of your example in your question is a good way to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Well I thought it was clear in the OP. But obviously not. Loop 1:table(rle(x)). Loop 2: table(rle(x)). << merge/combine/ the two tables into ubertable. Repeat for the full number of loops.

Comment: **but you still haven't told us what "merge/combine/the two tables into ubertable" means**.  I gave three answers above, and I still don't know whether any of them is really what you want.  If you show desired output, then any answer is clearly and unambiguously correct if it provides the desired output.  Is my last answer what you want, or not??  Do you want to keep the results from each run, or only the totals?  Do you want to keep the "0 runs" and "1 runs" length distributions separate or are you only interested in the overall run length distribution?

Comment: Can we state your question as being one of: "Count up the lengths of runs of 0s and 1s in a simulation of 100,000 coin tosses. Repeat 1 million times, aggregating the lengths of runs over all 1 million repetitions." In other words, all you want is a single table of run lengths for 0s and 1s built up by combining the individual run lengths from each of the 1 million simulations. Is that what you want? If so, Ben's second solution would be my way of choice, with a `colsums()` applied at the end of the loop to efficiently aggregate the results from individual simulations.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I believe you have got that correct. I will certainly delve deeper into Ben's second solution and see if I can use it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to read the help page for `rle` .  Consider:

```
names(rlex)  #"lengths"  "values"  "lengths"  "values" .... and so on
```

In the meantime,  I strongly suggest you spend some time reading up on statistical methods.   There is zero (+/- epsilon) chance that running a binomial simulation a million times will tell you anything you won't learn after a few hundred tries, unless your coin has p=1e-5 :-).